# Bash script get one directory back

Tags: bash, shell

I can get my current working directory with

```
my_dir=$(pwd)
echo $my_dir
/files/work/test
```

How do I get `/files/work`  I don't want to change directories.  I just need to get the `/files/work` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo `dirname \`pwd\``
```

It ll result the parent directory of present working directory

Comment: There is no need for `echo`, and `$(...)` is greatly preferred to backticks. `dirname "$(pwd)"`.

Answer (score 6):

Try one of these (assuming you didn't manually change `$PWD`):

1. ```
   echo "${PWD%/*}"
   ```
2. ```
   dirname "$PWD"
   ```
3. ```
   (cd .. && pwd)
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can ascend one directory above:

```
$ cd ..
```

or you can [dirname](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) to print the one directory above:

```
$ dirname "/files/work/test"
/files/work
```